# Sequential operation in GPU implementation

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I have to implement the following algorithm in GPU

```
for(int I = 0; I < 1000; I++){
    VAR1[I+1] = VAR1[I] + VAR2[2*K+(I-1)];//K is a constant
}
```

Each iteration is dependent on previous so the parallelizing is difficult. I am not sure if atomic operation is valid here. What can I do?

**EDIT:**

The **VAR1** and **VAR2** both are 1D array.

```
VAR1[0] = 1
```

Comment: @AngryLettuce Yes a little bit. I want to know the technique

Comment: With a little bit more information about this problem you have written, it might be quite simple to determine the closed form solution (for this *particular* case).  For example, what do `VAR1` and `VAR2` mean?  Is `VAR1` an array (it appears to be a 1D array).  Is `VAR2` a constant? If all of that is "yes", what is value of `VAR1[0]` (or, if you prefer, `VAR1[-1]`)?

Comment: VAR2 is a 1D array?  How does that work?  You haven't shown any indexing.    And what do you mean by "the first value" of VAR1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in a category of problems called [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). Depending on the structure of the recurrence relation, there may exist closed form solutions that describe how to compute each element individually (i.e. in parallel, without recursion). One of the early seminal papers (on parallel computation) was [Kogge and Stone](http://www.acsel-lab.com/Projects/fast_adder/references/papers/Kogge-Stone-73.pdf), and there exist recipes and strategies for parallelizing specific forms.

Sometimes recurrence relations are so simple that we can identify a closed-form formula or algorithm with a little bit of "inspection".  This [short tutorial](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Ejiang/cs141/recur-tut.txt) gives a little bit more treatment of this idea.

In your case, let's see if we can spot anything just by mapping out what the first few terms of `VAR1` should look like, substituting previous terms into newer terms:

```
i      VAR1[i]
___________________
0        1
1        1 + VAR2[2K-1]
2        1 + VAR2[2K-1] + VAR2[2K]
3        1 + VAR2[2K-1] + VAR2[2K] + VAR2[2K+1]
4        1 + VAR2[2K-1] + VAR2[2K] + VAR2[2K+1] + VAR2[2K+2]
...
```

Hopefully what jumps out at you is that the `VAR2[]` terms above follow a pattern of a [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).

This means one possible solution method could be given by:

```
VAR1[i] = 1+prefix_sum(VAR2[2K + (i-2)])   (for i > 0) notes:(1) (2)
VAR1[i] = 1                                (for i = 0)
```

Now, a prefix sum can be done in parallel (this is not truly a fully independent operation, but it can be parallelized.  I don't want to argue too much about terminology or purity here.  I'm offering *one possible method* of parallelization for your stated problem, not the only way to do it.)  To do a prefix sum in parallel on the GPU, I would use a library like [CUB](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html) or [Thrust](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html).  Or you can [write your own](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) although I wouldn't recommend it.

Notes:

1. the use of -1 or -2 as an offset to `i` for the prefix sum may be dictated by your use of an `inclusive` or `exclusive` scan or prefix sum operation.
2. `VAR2` must be defined over an appropriate domain to make this sensible.  However that requirement is implicit in your problem statement.

Here is a trivial worked example.  In this case, since the `VAR2` indexing term `2K+(I-1)` just represents a fixed offset to `I` (`2K-1`), we are simply using an offset of 0 for demonstration purposes, so `VAR2` is just a simple array over the same domain as `VAR1`.   And I am defining `VAR2` to just be an array of all `1`, for demonstration purposes. The gpu parallel computation occurs in the `VAR1` vector, the CPU equivalent computation is just computed on-the-fly in the `cpu` variable for validation purposes:

```
$ cat t1056.cu
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <iostream>

const int dsize = 1000;
using namespace thrust::placeholders;
int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<int> VAR2(dsize, 1);  // initialize VAR2 array to all 1's
  thrust::device_vector<int> VAR1(dsize);
  thrust::exclusive_scan(VAR2.begin(), VAR2.end(), VAR1.begin(), 0); // put prefix sum of VAR2 into VAR1
  thrust::transform(VAR1.begin(), VAR1.end(), VAR1.begin(),  _1 += 1);   // add 1 to every term
  int cpu = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < dsize; i++){
    int gpu = VAR1[i];
    cpu += VAR2[i];
    if (cpu != gpu) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << gpu << " should be: " << cpu << std::endl; return 1;}
    }
  std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t1056 t1056.cu
$ ./t1056
Success!
$
```

For an additional reference particular to the usage of scan operations to solve linear recurrence problems, refer to Blelloch's paper [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.128.6230&rep=rep1&type=pdf) section 1.4.  [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085324/cuda-force-instruction-execution-order) gives an example of how to implement the equation 1.5 in that paper for a more general first-order recurrence case. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128982/cuda-2nd-order-recursion-with-thrust-inclusive-scan) considers the second-order recurrence case.