# CUDA force instruction execution order

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to transfer some data manipulations from CPU to GPU (CUDA), but there's one small part that requires instructions to be run in a specific order.  In principle I could do the first few parallel parts, then transfer the results to the host for the serial part, then transfer it back again for the rest of the parallel parts, but I'm trying to avoid the memory transfer overhead.

The serial part of the calculation is of the form:

```
for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
{
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + result[i-1];
}
```

Other than launching a kernel on a single thread for this calculation, is there a way to force threads or calculations to run in a specific order?

**EDIT:**

The problem is slightly more complicated than I first showed, and as far as I can tell it doesn't work as a prefix sum problem.

The loop actually takes the form:

```
for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
{
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-1];
}
```

I've been looking through the documentation for the Thrust library, but that doesn't seem to have a solution.  However, I may have just not understood what I was looking at.  Is there a parallel solution to this sort of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible description we could give to problems like this is to put them in the category of *recurrence relations*.

The original question:

```
for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
{
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + result[i-1];
}
```

could be solved trivially with a prefix sum on `oldArray`, if need be following the description given in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868437/sequential-operation-in-gpu-implementation/34868913#34868913).

With the modification from the edit:

```
for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
{
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-1];
}
```

We have to do extra work.  Referring to the previously linked answer, at the bottom of that answer, reference is given to [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguyb/papers/Ble93.pdf) by Blelloch.  If we study section 1.4 of that paper, we can observe that this new problem formulation fits the pattern of the "First Order Recurrences" described in section 1.4.1, specifically formula 1.5.  A proof is provided there for how a solution to that formulation may be realized using a *scan* operation, if we carefully specify the input/output data as well as the scan operator.

Thrust has the ability to support these kinds of generalizations to the basic scans provided.  The sets of pairs in that paper referred to by `s` and `c` can be realized as `thrust::tuple`, and the specific operator can be passed to thrust scan operations, to generalize the operation behavior.

I'm not going to try to cover all the ground in that paper; we mostly only need to concern ourselves with the material presented on pages 48 and 49.

What follows then is an example using thrust demonstrating that we can use a thrust scan operation exactly as described in the paper, to solve this problem formulation.  The code below is annotated with comments that reference specific formulas in the Blelloch paper:

```
$ cat t1929.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
void cpufunction(T *result, T *oldArray, size_t size, T k){
  for (int i = 1; i<size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-1];
  }
}

struct scan_op // as per blelloch (1.7)
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  T1 operator()(const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2){
    T1 ret;
    thrust::get<0>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<0>(t2);
    thrust::get<1>(ret) = thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<0>(t2)+thrust::get<1>(t2);
    return ret;
    }
};

typedef float mt;
const size_t ds = 1048576;
const mt k = 1.01;
int main(){

  mt *b  = new mt[ds]; // b as in blelloch (1.5)
  mt *a  = new mt[ds]; // a as in blelloch (1.5)
  mt *cr = new mt[ds]; // cpu result
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) { a[i] = k; b[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;}
  cr[0] = b[0];
  cpufunction(cr, b, ds, k);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::device_vector<mt> db(b, b+ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> da(a, a+ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dx(ds);
  thrust::inclusive_scan(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(da.begin(), db.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(da.end(), db.end())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dy.begin(), dx.begin())), scan_op());
  thrust::host_vector<mt> hx = dx;
  thrust::copy_n(hx.begin(), 10, std::ostream_iterator<mt>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++14 t1929.cu -o t1929
$ ./t1929
0.840188,1.24297,2.0385,2.85733,3.79755,4.03307,4.40863,5.22094,5.55093,6.16041,
0.840188,1.24297,2.0385,2.85733,3.79755,4.03307,4.40863,5.22094,5.55093,6.16041,
```

The First Order Recurrence described by Blelloch allows for the possibility of a more-or-less arbitrary `a` array.  In this question, the `a` array is simply given by `k`, `k`, `k`, ...  We could probably further simplify this by eliminating the `a` array and replacing it with a `thrust::constant_iterator`. That exercise is fairly mechanical and is left to the reader.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you, one question:

I already have the equivalent of your `b` array on the device.  Should I declare it as a `thrust::device_vector` at the start, or should that wait until this stage?

Comment: You probably don't need to use a `thrust::device_vector` at all.  A thrust operation can work on "ordinary" device data as well.  There are 2 ways to do it, either as "raw" data, or via a pointer converted to a `thrust::device_pointer`.  There are questions and examples of how to do each of these on the `thrust` tag.  For the `zip_iterator` usage, a `thrust::device_pointer` should be fine.  You can convert your ordinary "raw" pointer to a `thrust::device_pointer`

Comment: I'm now trying to make what I _thought_ was a minor change for a related calculation.  I want everything the same but I want to replace `i-1` with `i-2`.  Following through the 1st order and higher order sections of the Blelloch paper, I can sort of see how the 2nd order version should work, but I not how to convert it into a format that works for the scan operation.  Any chance you can help?  Is it worth opening a new question for it?

Comment: I don't know if I can help.  Probably best to open a new question.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm very grateful for the help.

Comment: I provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70131921/1695960).

Comment: I've been doing some testing and on an array of just under 17M doubles, the `thrust::inclusive_scan` solution is about 50x slower than running the serial calculation on the CPU.  Is that expected?

Comment: I haven't done any careful testing.  When I ran the code for the very last case I posted in the 2nd order question you posted later than this one, that case (thrust kernels only, ds=256000, V100 GPU, `float` data) I got around 80 microseconds.  That seemed reasonably fast to me, as a kernel launch with nothing at all in it takes ~5 microseconds.  It's possible (I imagine) that the serial code is faster than 80 microseconds.  I didn't time that.

Comment: Ok, you have about 5x as many cores as me (Quadro P2200), I may not be able to convince my boss to buy me a $7k GPU though...

With 256k `double` I get 1.6 ms on CPU and 140 ms on GPU.  With 2.56M `double` it goes to 17 ms on CPU and just over 1s on GPU.  So they both scale pretty linearly, which makes sense, but the GPU seems weirdly slow.

Comment: When I run the last case I posted in the other answer, with ds of 256k and `double`, on a Maxwell GTX 960 GPU (smaller/less powerful than your Pascal P22200), and timing **only** the call to `thrust::inclusive_scan`, I get 972 microseconds for the `cpufunction` and 967 microseconds for the `thrust::inclusive_scan`.   I'm concerned on the GPU side that you are timing a **debug** project.  If that is the case, you should not.   Yes, if you add data transfer time and `cudaMalloc` time to that, the GPU will start to look worse.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the GPU to beat the CPU here on that single function alone.  You started out this discussion by saying "but there's one small part that requires instructions to be run in a specific order."  If this is one small part of a much larger workflow, then getting to parity here might be  a useful step.  But if you expect this operation, all by itself, to be much faster than the CPU, when you are doing all the overhead of data movement, then I would say you are probably wasting your time.

Comment: When I switch to `float` the above times I reported become: CPU: 315us, GPU: 183us.

Comment: Yes close to parity here would be more than fast enough to justify using the GPU.  I was just looking at different parts in isolation to see how things were scaling.  I'm only including the relevant function calls for timing in this case.  You are absolutely right about the **debug**, I'm new to NSight and hadn't even realised it was an option.  With a Release build and running from a real terminal not in the IDE gives ~90ms for CPU and ~7ms for GPU with 16M `double`.

Comment: For that case on my GTX 960 I see about 68ms for CPU and about 80ms for GPU.  So I am not sure I "believe" your 7ms number, but we may be timing different things.

Comment: I get the times to align with yours if I include the `DToH` and `HToD` data transfer.  In any case, everything now makes sense, and works perfectly thank you again.  If you ever want a lesson in accelerator physics, I'd be happy to return the favour.