# CUDA 2nd order recursion with thrust inclusive_scan

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to understand how to parallelise a recursive calculation.  Serially, the calculation takes the form:

```
for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-2];
  }
```

For the `i-1` index there's a solution here to a previous question of mine: [CUDA force instruction execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085324/cuda-force-instruction-execution-order/70116462?noredirect=1#comment123966566_70116462)

I want to modify this to use the `i-2` and I can't understand how to apply the same process to a 2nd order calculation.  It should be possible using the `thrust::inclusive_scan` function, but I can't work out how.  Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Higher-order recurrences can be expressed as a scan where the scan op involves vectors and matrices. see 1.4.2 in https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picking up where we left off in the previous question/answer, we shift our attention to equation 1.11 in the [referenced paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguyb/papers/Ble93.pdf) by Blelloch.  We observe that your problem formulation:

```
for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-2];
  }
```

seems to match that in equation 1.11 if we set m=2 and in that case we can also observe that for your formulation, all a<sub>i,1</sub> are zero  (and, as previously, all a<sub>i,2</sub> are k).

As per equation 1.12 in that paper, our state variable s<sub>i</sub> now becomes a two-tuple:

s<sub>i</sub> = |x<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i-1</sub>|

Taking note of these things, we observe the "correctness" of equation 1.13:

s<sub>i</sub> = |x<sub>i-1</sub> x<sub>i-2</sub>| . |0 1, k 0| + |b<sub>i</sub> 0|

rewriting:

s<sub>i,1</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> = k*x<sub>i-2</sub> + b<sub>i</sub>

s<sub>i,2</sub> = x<sub>i-1</sub> = x<sub>i-1</sub>

(In my view, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70129607/1695960) leaves you at this point.  That realization, i.e. `result.data[0] = right + k * left.data[1];` is sufficient for a serial scan but not for a parallel scan.  It's also evident that the functor/scan op there is not associative.)

We now need to come up with a binary operator `bop` that is an extension of the definition in (1.7) to this case. Referring to the previous definition in equation 1.7, we extend that based on the treatment in 1.13 as follows:

C<sub>i</sub> = |A<sub>i</sub> , B<sub>i</sub>|

where:

A<sub>i</sub> = |0 1, k 0|

and:

B<sub>i</sub> = |b<sub>i</sub> 0|

We then have:

C<sub>i</sub> `bop` C<sub>j</sub> = | A<sub>i</sub> . A<sub>j</sub> , B<sub>i</sub> . A<sub>j</sub> + B<sub>j</sub> |

This then becomes the formula for our functor/scan operator.  We will need to carry 6 scalar "state" quantities throughout: 2 for the B vector and 4 for the A matrix.

What follows then is a realization of the above:

```
$ cat t1930.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
template <typename T>
void cpufunction(T *result, T *oldArray, size_t size, T k){
  for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-2];
  }
}
struct scan_op // as per blelloch (1.7)
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  T1 operator()(const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2){
    T1 ret;
    thrust::get<0>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2)+thrust::get<0>(t2);
    thrust::get<1>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2)+thrust::get<1>(t2);
    thrust::get<2>(ret) = thrust::get<2>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<3>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2);
    thrust::get<3>(ret) = thrust::get<2>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<3>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2);
    thrust::get<4>(ret) = thrust::get<4>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<5>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2);
    thrust::get<5>(ret) = thrust::get<4>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<5>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2);
    return ret;
    }
};

typedef float mt;
const size_t ds = 512;
const mt k = 1.01;
const int snip = 10;
int main(){

  mt *b1  = new mt[ds]; // b as in blelloch (1.5)
  mt *cr = new mt[ds]; // cpu result
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) { b1[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;}
  cr[0] = b1[0];
  cr[1] = b1[1];
  cpufunction(cr, b1, ds, k);
  for (int i = 0; i < snip; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  for (int i = ds-snip; i < ds; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::device_vector<mt> db(b1, b1+ds);
  auto b0 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  auto a0 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  auto a1 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(1);
  auto a2 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(k);
  auto a3 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dx1(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dx0(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy0(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy1(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy2(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy3(ds);
  auto my_i_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(db.begin(), b0, a0, a1, a2, a3));
  auto my_o_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dx1.begin(), dx0.begin(), dy0.begin(), dy1.begin(), dy2.begin(), dy3.begin()));
  thrust::inclusive_scan(my_i_zip, my_i_zip+ds, my_o_zip, scan_op());
  thrust::host_vector<mt> hx1 = dx1;
  thrust::copy_n(hx1.begin(), snip, std::ostream_iterator<mt>(std::cout, ","));
  thrust::copy_n(hx1.begin()+ds-snip, snip, std::ostream_iterator<mt>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++14 t1930.cu -o t1930
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1930
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0.840188,0.394383,1.63169,1.19677,2.55965,1.40629,2.92047,2.18858,3.22745,2.76443,570.218,601.275,576.315,607.993,582.947,614.621,589.516,621.699,595.644,628.843,
0.840188,0.394383,1.63169,1.19677,2.55965,1.40629,2.92047,2.18858,3.22745,2.76443,570.219,601.275,576.316,607.994,582.948,614.621,589.516,621.7,595.644,628.843,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Yes, there are some results above that differ in the 6th digit.  I attribute this to the limitations of `float` resolution when taking into account the very different order of operations between the serial and parallel method.  If you change the `typedef` to `double`, the results will appear to match exactly.

Since you've asked about it here's an equivalent realization where it is demonstrated using device data previously allocated using `cudaMalloc`:

```
$ cat t1930.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
template <typename T>
void cpufunction(T *result, T *oldArray, size_t size, T k){
  for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-2];
  }
}
struct scan_op // as per blelloch (1.7)
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  T1 operator()(const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2){
    T1 ret;
    thrust::get<0>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2)+thrust::get<0>(t2);
    thrust::get<1>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2)+thrust::get<1>(t2);
    thrust::get<2>(ret) = thrust::get<2>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<3>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2);
    thrust::get<3>(ret) = thrust::get<2>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<3>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2);
    thrust::get<4>(ret) = thrust::get<4>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<5>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2);
    thrust::get<5>(ret) = thrust::get<4>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<5>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2);
    return ret;
    }
};

typedef double mt;
const size_t ds = 512;
const mt k = 1.01;
const int snip = 10;
int main(){

  mt *b1  = new mt[ds]; // b as in blelloch (1.5)
  mt *cr = new mt[ds]; // cpu result
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) { b1[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;}
  cr[0] = b1[0];
  cr[1] = b1[1];
  cpufunction(cr, b1, ds, k);
  for (int i = 0; i < snip; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  for (int i = ds-snip; i < ds; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  mt *db;
  cudaMalloc(&db, ds*sizeof(db[0]));
  cudaMemcpy(db, b1, ds*sizeof(db[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dp_db = thrust::device_pointer_cast(db);
  auto b0 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  auto a0 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  auto a1 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(1);
  auto a2 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(k);
  auto a3 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dx1(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dx0(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy0(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy1(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy2(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<mt> dy3(ds);
  auto my_i_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dp_db, b0, a0, a1, a2, a3));
  auto my_o_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dx1.begin(), dx0.begin(), dy0.begin(), dy1.begin(), dy2.begin(), dy3.begin()));
  thrust::inclusive_scan(my_i_zip, my_i_zip+ds, my_o_zip, scan_op());
  cudaMemcpy(cr, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dx1.data()), ds*sizeof(cr[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < snip; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  for (int i = ds-snip; i < ds; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++14 t1930.cu -o t1930
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1930
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0.840188,0.394383,1.63169,1.19677,2.55965,1.40629,2.92047,2.18858,3.22745,2.76443,570.219,601.275,576.316,607.994,582.948,614.622,589.516,621.7,595.645,628.844,
0.840188,0.394383,1.63169,1.19677,2.55965,1.40629,2.92047,2.18858,3.22745,2.76443,570.219,601.275,576.316,607.994,582.948,614.622,589.516,621.7,595.645,628.844,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

There should be no significant performance difference between these two approaches. (However I happened to switch the `typedef` to `double` for this example, so that makes a difference.)   Using `cudaMalloc` as an alternative to the `device_vector` for the various state vectors (`dx0`, `dx1`, `dy0`, `dy1` ...) may be slightly faster, because `device_vector` first does a `cudaMalloc` style allocation, then launches a kernel to zero out the allocation.  This zero-ing step is unnecessary for the state vectors.  The pattern given here should demonstrate how you could do that, if you are interested.

Here's a version that eliminates use of `thrust::device_vector` and `thrust::host_vector` altogether:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
void cpufunction(T *result, T *oldArray, size_t size, T k){
  for (int i = 2; i<size; i++)
  {
    result[i] = oldArray[i] + k * result[i-2];
  }
}
struct scan_op // as per blelloch (1.7)
{
  template <typename T1, typename T2>
  __host__ __device__
  T1 operator()(const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2){
    T1 ret;
    thrust::get<0>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2)+thrust::get<0>(t2);
    thrust::get<1>(ret) = thrust::get<0>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<1>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2)+thrust::get<1>(t2);
    thrust::get<2>(ret) = thrust::get<2>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<3>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2);
    thrust::get<3>(ret) = thrust::get<2>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<3>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2);
    thrust::get<4>(ret) = thrust::get<4>(t1)*thrust::get<2>(t2) + thrust::get<5>(t1)*thrust::get<4>(t2);
    thrust::get<5>(ret) = thrust::get<4>(t1)*thrust::get<3>(t2) + thrust::get<5>(t1)*thrust::get<5>(t2);
    return ret;
    }
};

typedef float mt;
const size_t ds = 32768*4;
const mt k = 1.001;
const int snip = 10;
int main(){

  mt *b1  = new mt[ds]; // b as in blelloch (1.5)
  mt *cr = new mt[ds]; // result
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) { b1[i] = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)-0.5;}
  cr[0] = b1[0];
  cr[1] = b1[1];
  cpufunction(cr, b1, ds, k);
  for (int i = 0; i < snip; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  for (int i = ds-snip; i < ds; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  mt *db, *dstate;
  cudaMalloc(&db, ds*sizeof(db[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&dstate, 6*ds*sizeof(dstate[0]));
  cudaMemcpy(db, b1, ds*sizeof(db[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dp_db = thrust::device_pointer_cast(db);
  auto b0 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  auto a0 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  auto a1 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(1);
  auto a2 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(k);
  auto a3 = thrust::constant_iterator<mt>(0);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dx1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dstate);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dx0 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dstate+ds);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dy0 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dstate+2*ds);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dy1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dstate+3*ds);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dy2 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dstate+4*ds);
  thrust::device_ptr<mt> dy3 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dstate+5*ds);
  auto my_i_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dp_db, b0, a0, a1, a2, a3));
  auto my_o_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dx1, dx0, dy0, dy1, dy2, dy3));
  thrust::inclusive_scan(my_i_zip, my_i_zip+ds, my_o_zip, scan_op());
  cudaMemcpy(cr, dstate, ds*sizeof(cr[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < snip; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  for (int i = ds-snip; i < ds; i++) std::cout << cr[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Great. I must have missed 1.7 . Indeed, the scan op I used is not associative which prevents parallel computation. I will update my answer.

Comment: I was closer than I realised, I couldn't get the indexing right.  You said in the other question that `device_vector` isn't necessary.  Is there a performance advantage to using them, or are you doing it here for convenience?

Comment: It's just a matter of convenience.  There should be no performance difference between using an allocation created with `cudaMalloc` and using an allocation created with `thrust::device_vector`  Anyway since you've asked about it, I provided a similar example using `cudaMalloc` and `thrust::device_ptr`

Comment: I tried, and I seem to get quite a meaningful advantage if I use `cudaMalloc`.  It's fast either way, but if I do `cudaMalloc` for the input, output, dy and dx it's about 200 ms of `cudaMalloc` time (according to nvvp).  If I use `thrust::device_vector` for dy and dx, the `cudaMalloc` is roughly the same, but the two vector declarations take ~50 ms each (again nvvp).  I tried doing a basic timing in the main function with `clock()`, and see roughly the same thing as well.

Comment: When I run the last test case on a V100 GPU I get around 80 microseconds for the kernels associated with the `inclusive_scan`.  The first CUDA call (e.g. `cudaMalloc` ) in any program is going to be long, like hundreds of milliseconds. If this is part of some other work you are doing, you won't see that here.  Thereafter the `cudaMalloc` operations should be in the 50 microsecond range.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some cpu code which shows a possible implementation of the formular derived from [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguyb/papers/Ble93.pdf) to express higher-order recurrences as a scan operation.

The key idea is that each element of the scan result is not a scalar, but a vector which contains the n previous scalar results. This way, all the required previous results are available in the scan operator to compute the next result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>

void calculate1(std::vector<int> vec, int k){
    std::vector<int> result(vec.size(), 0);

    for(int i = 2; i < vec.size(); i++){
        result[i] = vec[i] + k * result[i-2];
        
    }

    std::cerr << "calculate1 result: ";
    for(auto x : result){
        std::cerr << x << ", ";
    }
    std::cerr << "\n";
}


struct S{
    //data[0] stores result of last iteration
    //data[1] stores result of second last iteration
    std::array<int, 2> data;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, S s){
    os << "(" << s.data[0] << "," << s.data[1] << ")";
}

void calculate2(std::vector<int> vec, int k){
    S initvalue{{0,0}};
    std::vector<S> result(vec.size(), initvalue);

    std::exclusive_scan(
        vec.begin() + 2, 
        vec.end(), 
        result.begin(), 
        initvalue,
        [k](S left, int right){
            S result;
            /*A = (
                0 1
                k 0
            )
            Compute result = left * A + (right 0)
            */
            result.data[0] = right + k * left.data[1];
            result.data[1] = left.data[0];
            return result;
        }
    );

    std::cerr << "calculate2 result: ";
    for(auto x : result){
        std::cerr << x << ", ";
    }
    std::cerr << "\n";
}

int main(){
    const int k = 5;
    const std::vector<int> vec1{1,3,5,7,9,11,3,6,7,1,2,4};

    calculate1(vec1, k);
    calculate2(vec1, k);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cszzn8Ec8

Output:

```
calculate1 result: 0, 0, 5, 7, 34, 46, 173, 236, 872, 1181, 4362, 5909, 
calculate2 result: (0,0), (5,0), (7,5), (34,7), (46,34), (173,46), (236,173), (872,236), (1181,872), (4362,1181), (0,0), (0,0),
```

There is still an of-by-one error somewhere, but one can get the idea behind it.

I previously said that this approach can be used for a parallel scan in CUDA. This is not correct. For a parallel scan, the scan operator must have an additional property, which is associativity, i.e. (a OP b) OP c == a OP (b OP c). This is not the case in this approach.

Robert Crovella's answer shows how to derive an associative scan operator which can be used for a parallel scan.